# Shall I use SPA or traditional approach with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS, I have following scenario that I need to implement: 
Assume index.html page only has an input field for enter a unique ID, when click submit button, the unique ID will be passed to backend for retrieving all information needed(for example, User object with current status, last name, first name etc ). Based on User.currentStatus, it should show different page with the same header and footer. There is no top menu bar on any of the page. Basically, all the pages are displaying different information about a user based on his status.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, it depends on your backend architecture, but if you're new to Angular I'd recommend a SPA, since most resources are geared towards building a SPA.

Answer (score -1):

Angular can be used either "traditionally" or in a SPA environment. Given that Angular does specifically target use in SPA's, that's the path I suggest.

Here's is a reference to $route in the AngularJS documentation, which you'll need in order to build a SPA: [$route](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route)

You'll also need to read up on ngView, which is referenced near the top of that page.

For a SPA, structuring the project well can make things a whole lot easier, so here's a reference to a [good style guide](http://toddmotto.com/opinionated-angular-js-styleguide-for-teams/) for Angular as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now my next question is, how to assign different view path in controller based on the input (User.status). Say that I use ng-view in html file, and I have to define where to go (URL) in controller.